# Is Possible Just Using References DLL Than .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have developed VB.NET app. I want to run my app without .NET Framework. I have google it and many developer said you cannot. And then I think how if I just use DLL that I use. For example. I just use **System.Windows.Forms**

If possible I just use that DLL? I found "Copy Local"(set it to "true") in References tab. But I don't know how it's work. I have tried it but fail. Got "The application failed to ...". Yes, I know this because .NET Framework haven't installed yet.

This I want to ask:

- If possible if I just use that DLL rather than install .NET Framework?
- Am I doing it wrong about "Copy Local"?

I have google this topic but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: But which DLLs does System.Windows.Forms use?

Comment: It's not possible - but don't forget that every version of Windows since Vista has at least .Net Framework 2

Comment: Actually Vista comes with .NET 3.0, and also MS pushed some years ago .NET 3.5 to windows update. So it should be on most machines already. If you are using .NET you cannot escape having the runtime on client machine.

Answer (score 3):

> If possible I just use that DLL?

No. Because you're *not* just using the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly... you're almost certainly using the `System` assembly, and you'll *definitely* be using `mscorlib`... and `System.Windows.Forms` probably depends on a bunch of other assemblies.

Add to that the fact that you're using the CLR (the runtime) in the first place... that's what *understands* DLLs like this rather than just DLLs with native code. Basically you *do* need .NET.

You may well be able to target the Client Profile for some particular version of the framework, so that users don't need to install as much... but fundamentally you'll need the .NET framework in some form or other.

There are some alternatives to full installation, such as [VMware ThinApp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ThinApp) - but I'd suggest that in *most* cases, doing something like that is going to add to the maintenance headache, as you're then running in a subtly different environment to the one most .NET developers envisage.